# Lamports not working when dealing with AccountInfo within Solang

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solang

When trying to build a program with this function (from one of the exmaples given):

```
    function transferSolWithCpi(uint64 lamports) public {
        AccountInfo from = tx.accounts[0]; // first account must be an account owned by the program
        AccountInfo to = tx.accounts[1]; // second account must be the intended recipient

        print("From: {:}".format(from.key));
        print("To: {:}".format(to.key));

        from.lamports -= lamports;
        to.lamports += lamports;
    }
```

I get a failed build saying:

```
error: assigning to incorrect type uint64
   ┌─ /mnt/c/<my-path>/solidity/tryPay.sol:38:14
   │
38 │         from.lamports -= lamports;
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this? I copied the exact same code as in the example

Comment: This was due to a bug with Solang, but it seems to have been fixed: https://github.com/hyperledger/solang/issues/1445

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up! It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using v0.3.2 of Solang, which seems to include the fix
https://github.com/hyperledger/solang/releases/tag/v0.3.2

> Solana The lamports and data fields of tx.accounts can be modified
> again.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up! It worked